# Executing sudo command from java after trying every standard lib options

Tags: java, shell, execute, sudo

I need to run sudo from Java and I have tried following options:

- Runtime.exec(Every form of "echo password | sudo -S"). Every form of the commands can be successfully executed directly from terminal, but not from java despite correctly specifying path to the program
- ProcessBuilder in ThreadExecutor, as seen [here](http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-exec-processbuilder-process-1)

The options of editing sudoers and running Java process as root are not viable for my case.
Is [this](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Sudo.java.html) really my only option left because I am really trying to avoid using any non-standard libs?

EDIT: Seems there is no way around this other than requiring the user to exclusively download a SUDO GUI (kdesudo, gksu, cocoasudo, etc.) and then provide the path to java.

Comment: Question is closed as "not a real question". What does this even mean? My question very clearly states which options I have left other than using a non-standard lib to execute a sudo command from java because every options provided by google prove to be not working at all.

Answer (score 1):

Storing your root password in your java application is a terrible horrible no good very bad idea.  I suggest you approach this problem differently, such as with different sudo configuration (so it doesn't require a password from whichever account), a SUID binary wrapper, or something similar.

Comment: "Different sudo configuration" Do you mean this as editing sudoers? If so then it is not viable for my case. Probably it will be best if I specify what I have to do. I have to make the command available for every (atm only linux)-system it is run on. This is the reason why editing sudoers or starting Java with root priviledge is not viable.

Comment: beware that not every system might come with sudo installed..

Comment: @KristofJozsa: since he specifically mentioned it in the question, I'm going to go out on a limb and say he has it

Answer (score 0):

Did "every form" include "bash -c 'echo password | sudo -S'" ?

Comment: Yes it did include the bash -c form

Comment: hmm if it worked from the shell directly, it really should work this way too then..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Process`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) object obtained to access the input, [output](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getOutputStream%28%29), and error streams connected to the process's standard out, in, and error.

This way you can send input to the child process and read its output back.

Comment: This option has been tried, as linked in option 2. The author did exactly this and it unfortunately proved to no avail for me. It hangs on password prompt from the terminal.

Comment: I can't really see where it was tried this way. However, you did try using the input and output streams of a process executing "sudo" without the "echo"? - And: The pipe "|" is actually a feature of the *shell*. So you may also want to try to execute the *shell* and pass it your (shell) commands as input like it's done on page 2 of the referenced article.

Comment: Yes, I executed the command with sudo -S ..., without the echo. I did what the author did in all 3 pages of the referenced article.

Comment: Ok, out of ideas now :-\

Comment: Thank you for your answers nevertheless.